# Heroku tutorial foreman crashing (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, node.js, ubuntu, heroku, foreman

Going through the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally) on Ubuntu 14.10 after a clean install, got to launching the app locally, but foreman crashes:

```
$ foreman start web
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'foreman' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/foreman:23:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. It looks like Heroku half-installed foreman. Following the error message I tried:

```
sudo gem install foreman
```

and now foreman runs without crashing